# What command will wake up a sleeping USB drive?

Tags: command-line, usb, mount, power-management

I have an power-managed USB drive that powers down when not in use, and wakes up automatically when accessed. It's used as a backup drive from a root script which mounts it when necessary. Sometimes the mount command fails because I suspect that it doesn't always wait for the drive to spin up (although this is a guess).

I'd like to put a command in the script that will probe the drive and cause it to spin up so it's ready when the mount is issued. I've tried `lsusb` but that doesn't work, and file system commands don't either as it's not mounted yet. `fdisk -l` does appear to work, but is there something better I could use?

UPDATE

As suggested by @vidarlo I checked out dmesg after the next time the mount failed:

`[Sun Aug  5 01:30:04 2018] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:04 2018] usb 1-1: device firmware changed
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:04 2018] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:04 2018] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:04 2018] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 41 00 00 02 00
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:04 2018] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 65
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:04 2018] EXT4-fs (sdb1): unable to read superblock
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:04 2018] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:05 2018] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2339
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:05 2018] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:05 2018] usb 1-1: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:05 2018] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: JMicron
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:05 2018] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 152D203380B6
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:05 2018] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:05 2018] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:07 2018] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SAMSUNG  HD321KJ               PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:07 2018] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:07 2018] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 625142448 512-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:07 2018] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:07 2018] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 38 00 00
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:07 2018] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:07 2018] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:08 2018]  sdb: sdb1
[Sun Aug  5 01:30:08 2018] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk`

Regardless of the error the drive appears to end up becoming available. I believe that if I'd rerun the backup script at this point it would have worked.

Answer (score 2):

Any read should trigger it:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdx1 bs=1k count=1 of=/dev/zero
```

will attempt to read from it and should wake it up.

Note that I somewhat doubt that this is the reason mount does not work. Do you get any error messages? What does `dmesg | tail -n 25` show after a failed mount attempt?

Comment: I'm not assuming I know the device name, so I couldn't use that.  However, if you doubt my guess at the reason for  the error (yes, mea culpa, I should have done this already)  then perhaps I should just wait for it to happen again and investigate properly.

Comment: Use `/dev/disk-by-uuid/UUID` in place of `/dev/sdx1` if you go by UUID when mounting.

Comment: Write unwanted output to `/dev/null`, not `/dev/zero`.

Comment: @waltinator [Why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254384/difference-between-dev-null-and-dev-zero) Both accept and discard any input.

Comment: `/dev/zero` is designed to produce `\000` bytes, and `/dev/null` is designed to discard its input. For clarity (to help subsequent readers) `/dev/null` is clearer. In your example, the use of `of=/dev/zero` could make one wonder if you really meant `if=/dev/zero`, and OP ends up wiping the disk.

Comment: `/dev/null` is designed to discard any input and produce EOF as output. `/dev/zero` is designed to discard any input and produce NULL as output. For reading it makes a difference. For discarding data it makes zero (pun intended) difference.

Comment: Due to caching my HDD wouldn't wake up with the above command. So you need to add `iflag=direct` to the dd command so that it doesn't use the cache.

Answer (score 1):

## Sleeping power-managed USB drive

Your power-managed USB drive powers down when not in use, and wakes up automatically when accessed, but sometimes too slowly. In this case it it neither unmounted nor ejected, and I think the command

```
sudo partprobe
```

should wake it up.

---

### Sleep

Not in this case but in some related cases

```
sleep 5
```

would help by giving the operating system 5 seconds to get ready for the next command (the backup).

### Unmount

If you have unmounted all partitions on a USB drive with `sudo umount ...`, it is still powered on and connected to a `/dev/sdx` (where `x` is the drive letter, for example `b` or `c`), and you can mount the partitions on it again with `sudo mount ...`.

### Eject

If you have ejected a USB pendrive, which is the typical action from the file browser, when you click on the eject icon, all partitions on it are unmounted and it is *powered off* and no longer connected to `/dev/sdx`. I means that you cannot wake it up with any command by pointing to `/dev/sdx`.

#### Unplug and plug in again

When you unplug and plug an ejected USB drive in again, it will be powered on and connected to `/dev/sdx`.

#### Warning: never unplug a USB drive that has a mounted partition

Never unplug a USB drive, that has a mounted partition, because there is a high risk, that the file system in the partition will be corrupted.

So you must *unmount* or *eject* (or shutdown the computer) before unplugging.

Comment: `partprobe` looks useful thanks (actually `partprobe -d` better in my case) and is simple to use, although perhaps no more so than `fdisk -l > /dev/null`.  Since the command doesn't complete until the disk is spun up and read I don't see why the sleep command is needed.

Comment: @ceperman, I see, and I will modify the answer (put less emphasis on sleep).